# ¿Cómo se llama la construcción 'se + verbo + a' que no es la pasiva refleja ni el se impersonal?

Tags: gramática, voz-pasiva

En *[A New Reference Grammar of Modern Spanish](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/413598.A_New_Reference_Grammar_of_Modern_Spanish)*, 4th ed., John Butt distingue las construcciones pasivas con *se*

- "impersonal se" (se impersonal)
- "passive se" (pasiva refleja)

y una construcción que llama

- "se + verb + a"

sobre que dice

> Passive *se*...is usually unambiguous if there is no noun in the
>   sentence that could be understood to be the subject, as it usually the
>   case when talking about non-living things: *los platos se lavan* 'the
>   plates are washed' is unlikely to mean 'the plates wash themselves',
>   which could be said *los platos se lavan a sí mismos*...However *se*
>   may be intolerably ambiguous with nouns referring to creatures that can
>   do things to themselves: *se mataron dos ingleses* could mean 'two
>   Englishmen killed themselves' as well as 'killed one another'. 
>   Spanish has developed a way of avoiding this problem by marking the
>   direct object by the preposition *a* : *se mató a dos ingleses* (p.413)

¿Cuál es el nombre de este tipo de construcción? ¿Me dirigís a la sección relevante en la gramática de RAE?  Estoy estudiando (de nuevo) las formas de *se*, y no veo esta forma en fuentes como, por ejemplo, [esta](https://tranquilacion.wordpress.com/2012/06/16/usos-del-se-y-ejercicios/).

¡Gracias por cualquier pista!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa forma no es específica de la pasiva. Fíjate en que en voz activa la preposición también es necesaria para eliminar la ambigüedad:

> Los alemanes mataron **a** dos ingleses.
>
> **A** los alemanes mataron dos ingleses.

[En el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=a) podemos encontrar que el uso de **"a"** antes del complemento directo se da (normalmente) cuando el complemento directo se refiere a personas o animales. En algunos casos es forzoso, en otros es opcional y en algunos muy específicos no se usa (por ejemplo, ante nombres comunes de persona en plural sin determinante).

Comment: Gracias, ya sabía lo de la 'a' personal.  ¿Entonces, esta construcción solo es un ejemplo de ésta?  Butt da una explicación larga de esta construcción, por tanto pensaba que era algo especial.

Comment: Sí, no hay una construcción específica de "se" + verbo + "a".

Comment: Pues es un 'se impersonal'?

Comment: "Se mataron dos ingleses" sería pasiva refleja o bien activa reflexiva o recíproca (es ambiguo, como dice Butt). "Se mató a dos ingleses" es pasiva impersonal.